# How to retrieve Table structure from sqlite3 (.db ) database using python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to get table structure using python from sqlite3 (.db) database. for that I am using the below code, but it is giving syntax error any help?

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('Db-IMDB.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('DESCRIBE Movie')
```

Comment: Sqlite dialect sql is documented at https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not MySQL, but sqlite3. In Python API you can retrieve information on table from this statement:

```
table_info = cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';").fetchall()
```